# Make Compose key work while pressed

Tags: keyboard-layout, compose-key

I'd like my Compose key to start composing the sequence without having to release it first. This used to work but now it doesn't, and now I'm not sure if I changed something or the input methods have changed.

My config is the following:

```bash
$ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options
['altwin:meta_win', 'caps:escape', 'compose:ralt', 'lv3:menu_switch', 'keypad:atm', 'kpdl:semi', 'numpad:shift3', 'nbsp:level2']
```

Note the `compose:ralt`, meaning I'm using the right alt as the compose key. The `lv3:menu_switch` is there to prevent the right alt from behaving also as the 3rd level switch.

What I have currently:

- Pressing `Compose` then `'` then `a`, or `Compose` then `a` then `'` → `á`
- Pressing `Compose` + `'` then `a`, or `Compose` + `a` then `'` → unfinished compose sequence

Basically I'd like the compose key to act on key down, while currently it seems to be acting on key up.

This is driving me nuts and I couldn't find a solution in any manual. I'm using GDM 44.1 and GNOME Shell 44.2 on Arch Linux.